# How do you get files with extension from folder in Ada95?

Tags: directory, ada

I'm trying to create a function that will look for all .dll files in a specified folder, plugins.

All of my web searches ([Ada Directories](http://wiki.ada-dk.org/ada.directories)) have work perfectly under Ada 2005, but I need a function that will work for Ada 95. It is to my knowledge that Ada 95 does not have the Ada.Directories extension.

How would I go about walking through the file system to find .dll files in Ada 95? Are there any good starting points out there that I may have overlooked?

Comment: It's worth asking if you really need to use a 20-year old version of the language. In most of the world, Ada-95 is old enough to buy a drink!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is (as you have noticed) no solution to your problem in the Ada 95 standard libraries.

If your program is for GNAT only, you could use `GNAT.Directory_Operations`.

If your program is for Unix systems only, but not only for GNAT, you could import the relevant C functions.